# Cannot access 'z' before initialization

Tags: javascript

```js
var w = 1, z = 2;
function foo( x = w + 1, y = x + 1, z = z + 1 ) {
  console.log(x, y, z);
};
foo(); // ReferenceError: Cannot access 'z' before initialization
```

Why `z` won't find `z = 2`, but `w` can find `w = 1`?

Comment: There are 2 `z`'s; which do you mean?

Comment: you're defining a new z inside `foo()` params

Comment: What do you think `z = z + 1` would produce? Ignore the first line of code, you're declaring `z` *here*, this code states "I want a `z` variable that is equal to the variable that is not created yet plus one".

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = 1, z = 2;
function foo( x = w + 1, y = x + 1, t = z + 1 ) {
  console.log(x, y, t);
};
foo();
```

Try this. You initialize z at start, then you initialize it again in the function declaration.

I've renamed `z` variable to `t`.